# How to get COLORREF from DwmGetColorizationColor

Tags: c++, dll, dllexport, dwm

I am extremely new and I do not understand what to do. I am making a DLL in C++ for a game I am working on in another language. I know nothing about C++ and have been barely been working myself through it. I need it to return the windows personalization color. Someone on reddit gracefully gave me some source that worked but it only returned the ACTIVE_BORDER color which is not the same color that users can easily change in windows 8+ which is what I am focusing on. I have modified it to work with DwmGetColorizationColor but now the problem is that it doesn't use a COLORREF which is what I need. Anyone who can help me out would be greatly appreciated.

Heres my source:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#define DLLEXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#pragma comment(lib, "Dwmapi")

DLLEXPORT double GetCol(void) {
    DWORD color = 0;
    BOOL opaque = FALSE;
    HRESULT hr = DwmGetColorizationColor(&color, &opaque);
    return color;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The returned color is in the format of

```
0xAArrggbb
```

Whereas a Windows `COLORREF` is

```
0x00bbggrr
```

You need to shift around the parts of your returned `DWORD` to to into a COLORREF.

```
COLORREF c = 
   ((color and 0x00ff0000) shr 16) //red
   or
   ((color and 0x0000ff00)) //green
   or
   ((color and 0x000000ff) shl 16);
```

Comment: I know this is a really old answer but if you still out there please replace && with & and || with |. I was too lazy to do it myself so I used this code and took me some minutes to actually see the bug. :)